# Form not validating inside modal popup when using jquery validator in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form it was validating when it was place on page but when i moved it to bootstrap modal it is not validating and the form is getting reloaded.Some fields will be dynamically added to modal that's why i used this for inside foreach loop to validate dynamic elements. Issue is it is closing when i press submit button.

> Script:

```
<script>
  $('form#frmaddclass').on('submit', function(event) {
    $('.form-control').each(function() {
  
        $(this).rules("add", 
            {
                required: true,
               
            });
    });
   });

   $("#frmaddclass").validate();
</script>
```

> HTML:

```
{{  Form::open(array('route' => 'add-class','class'=>'addclass','id'=>'frmaddclass')) }}   
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         {{ Form::text('class_name','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Class Name','id'=>'class_name']) }}
  
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link waves-effect btnaddclass">SAVE CHANGES</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
                        </div>
{{ Form::close()}}
```

Validation message in popover:

[image]

Comment: Show us the actual rendered HTML for the form rather than the Laravel code.

Comment: The popup closing when you press the button has nothing to do with jQuery Validate.  Either the validate plugin is validating or it isn't... it cannot control your popup windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have a submit handler.  If the form's HTML markup exists in the DOM, then call the `.rules()` method when the page is loaded.  Keep in mind that you should have already called `.validate()` before calling `.rules('add')`.

```
<script>
    $(function() {  // ready event handler

        $("#frmaddclass").validate();  // initialize plugin

        $('.form-control').each(function() {  // dynamically add the rules
            $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true,   
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

However, since you're just adding `required` rule to everything, there really isn't a need for the `.rules('add')` method.  Just put `required` attribute within the markup and the jQuery Validate method will pick this up automatically.

Comment: Thanks now i' getting validation message in popover but i want it below every fields that are being validated in simple text as normally jquery validator does.

Comment: @user3653474, the popover tooltip is HTML5 browser validation.  It means that your jQuery Validation is broken.  Please include a more complete demo in your OP so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: i have added running example in the above question, i think it is because my fields are dynamically added in the modal, in the example i have added one field dynamically but it is not validating. Please check by clicking on load input button.

Comment: @user3653474, there is no working example in your OP... you don't even show us the rendered HTML markup.